# Gatsby build command - contentful plugin not getting spaceId & accessToken from .env file

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, gatsby, contentful

I've been working on this for several hours and have been trying out a number of suggestions in similar questions here.

I can run my gatsby site develop build just fine, but when I run "gatsby build" I'm running into this error.

```
Invalid plugin options for "gatsby-source-contentful":

- "accessToken" is required
- "spaceId" is required

not finished open and validate gatsby-configs, load plugins - 1.427s
```

I have one .env file named ".env" with both of the necessary env variables, and in my gatsby-config file, I have it configured like this...

```
resolve: 'gatsby-source-contentful',
      options: {
        spaceId: process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID,
        accessToken: process.env.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN
      }
```

I've tested out the accessToken and spaceId by manually adding them into my gatsby-config plugins options and ran "gatsby build" and they are working fine. When I change the config back to the env variables though, it's no good and I get the error I mentioned previously.

One thing I tried just recently was to make another .env file and name it ".env.production" and it threw a different error like this...

```
“error Cannot access Contentful space “*********ab” on environment “master” with access token “***************************************1234”. Make sure to double check them! (value)”
```

This led me to look into the master environment on contentful but I'm pretty new to it and it's got me confused.

I can find a lot of questions here with the same type of problem but I'm yet to find a solution that works. Any gatsby experts out there who've had this problem?

Comment: please show a redacted version of .env file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Environment variables docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/local-development/environment-variables/):

> In development, Gatsby will load environment variables from a file
> named `.env.development`. For builds, it will load from `.env.production`.

So, in your scenario, just duplicate and rename your `.env` file to `.env.development` and `.env.production`. Gatsby will take the needed data depending on the fired command.